# Android get near by places and their extended place data (phone, rating, open hours...)

Tags: android, google-maps, url, android-asynctask

I am writing an Android app that display pizza places near your location
to do that I am using a call to google map using URL:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location={latitude,longitude}&type=pizza&sensor=true&key={MY_KEY}

I am processing the data by extending AsyncTask and using methods doInBackground and onPostExecute.

From the data I am getting and parsing I get the place id, now I want to call google again to get the place information phone, rating, is open ... (you do not get this data from the near by places information) I saw you can make a URL call to google using:
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key={MY_KEY}&placeid={PLACE_ID}

but I do not want to call AsyncTask  inside an AsyncTask.
basically I want to call the first URL and while parsing each place get the extended information.

How can i do that? 
my code is:

public class MapGetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask {

```
public final static int MAP_INDEX = 0;
public final static int URL_INDEX = 1;
private String googlePlacesData;
private GoogleMap map;
private String url;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Object... objects) {
    this.map = (GoogleMap)objects[MAP_INDEX];
    this.url = (String)objects[URL_INDEX];

    try {
        this.googlePlacesData = MapDownloadURL.readUrl(this.url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return this.googlePlacesData;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList;
    nearbyPlaceList = MapDataParser.parseNearbyPlaces(s);
    showNearbyPlaces(nearbyPlaceList);
}

private void showNearbyPlaces(List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlaceList) {
    for(int i = 0; i < nearbyPlaceList.size(); i++) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        HashMap<String, String> googlePlace = nearbyPlaceList.get(i);

        String placeName = googlePlace.get(StringUtils.MAP_PALACE_NAME);
        String vicinity = googlePlace.get(StringUtils.MAP_VICINITY);
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get(StringUtils.MAP_LATITUDE));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(googlePlace.get(StringUtils.MAP_LONGITUDE));
        String placeId = googlePlace.get(StringUtils.PLACE_ID);

       //how can I get the extended place info here?


        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        //build all necessary information to display in info window.
        String title = new StringBuilder()
                .append(placeName).append(StringUtils.infoWindowSplitter)
                .append(vicinity).append(StringUtils.infoWindowSplitter)
                .append(placeId).toString();

        markerOptions.title(title);
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
        this.map.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Please refer Google places APIs:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="+lat+","+lng+"&radius=10000&type=PlaceType&key=*************************
```

For key read documentation :
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest using the Java client library for Google Maps API Web Services to execute the Places API requests in your AsyncTask.

https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

With this library you can execute nearby search, get places and loop through items and execute place details to get the most complete place data.

You can add Java client library in your project via Gradle

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:(insert latest version)'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
}`

To demonstrate how it works I created a simple example. Have a look at implementation of MapGetNearbyPlacesData class.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();

                LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(context);
                info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                TextView title = new TextView(context);
                title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = new TextView(context);
                snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                info.addView(title);
                info.addView(snippet);

                return info;
            }
        });

        LatLng center = new LatLng(41.385064,2.173403);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 13.0f));

        new MapGetNearbyPlacesData().execute(mMap);
    }

    private static class MapGetNearbyPlacesData extends AsyncTask<GoogleMap, Void, List<MarkerOptions>> {

        private GoogleMap map;
        private String TAG = "so49343164";

        @Override
        protected List<MarkerOptions> doInBackground(GoogleMap... maps) {
            this.map = maps[0];

            List<MarkerOptions> options = new ArrayList<>();

            GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                    .apiKey("AIza......")
                    .build();

            NearbySearchRequest req = PlacesApi.nearbySearchQuery(context, new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(41.385064,2.173403));
            try {
                PlacesSearchResponse resp = req.keyword("pizza").type(PlaceType.RESTAURANT).radius(2000).await();
                if (resp.results != null && resp.results.length > 0) {
                    for (PlacesSearchResult r : resp.results) {
                        PlaceDetails details = PlacesApi.placeDetails(context,r.placeId).await();

                        String name = details.name;
                        String address = details.formattedAddress;
                        URL icon = details.icon;
                        double lat = details.geometry.location.lat;
                        double lng = details.geometry.location.lng;
                        String vicinity = details.vicinity;
                        String placeId = details.placeId;
                        String phoneNum = details.internationalPhoneNumber;
                        String[] openHours = details.openingHours!=null ? details.openingHours.weekdayText : new String[0];
                        String hoursText = "";
                        for(String sv : openHours) {
                            hoursText += sv + "\n";
                        }
                        float rating = details.rating;

                        String content = address + "\n" +
                                "Place ID: " + placeId + "\n" +
                                "Rating: " + rating + "\n" +
                                "Phone: " + phoneNum + "\n" +
                                "Open Hours: \n" + hoursText;

                        options.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
                                .title(name)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(icon.openConnection().getInputStream())))
                                .snippet(content)
                        );
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting places", e);
            }
            return options;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MarkerOptions> options) {
            for(MarkerOptions opts : options) {
                this.map.addMarker(opts);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

The result is

[image]

You can also find the complete sample project at GitHub:

https://github.com/xomena-so/so49343164

Do not forget replace API key with your's API key.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I would create a new async task that gets detailed information. Then look through your results in the first async tasks onPpstExucute function.